# How many days per ref in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, I get an item about every 45 minutes. So how many days would it take for me to get enough weapons to smelt up to one refined metal, considering I'm playing for about 45 minutes a day?

Comment: Item drops happen every 30-70 minutes (average 50), so 45 isn't always going to be long enough to get one.

Comment: There's also a cap on how long you can get items for per week, but if you're only playing for 45 minutes a day you won't hit it (it's somewhere around 10 hours per week, resetting at iirc 0:00 UTC Wednesday).

Comment: Thanks @Powerlord, I've incorporated the drop range into my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bare minimum? Given 1 Refined == 9 Scrap at 2 weapons apiece, **18 play sessions of ~45-50mins**.

A drop can happen anywhere between 30 and 70 minutes (with 50 minutes being the average), so you may have to vary your play times a bit if you want to guarantee a drop.

Of course, all this is assuming that each drop is a **compatible** class weapon to be used in smelting. Remember, in order to scrap two weapons, they must come from the same class. For example,

- You **can** scrap a *Sandvich* with a *Tomislav* (both for Heavy)
- You **can** scrap a *Force-a-Nature* with a *Mad Milk* (both for Scout)
- You **can't** scrap a *Sandvich* (Heavy) with a *Mad Milk* (Scout)

So realistically it will probably take a bit longer than 18 sessions.

You could also swap/trade for compatible weapons to make the process quicker. Sites like [Scrap.TF](https://scrap.tf/) make this easier. Of course,  once you go down that route it may just be easier to trade for what you want rather than worrying about scrapping & crafting stuff.

You can read more about [Drops](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system) and [Crafting](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting) on the TF2 Wiki.

Comment: I'm not affiliated with Scrap.TF btw, but I have used them in the past.

Comment: i absolutely LOVE scrap.tf, so considering I use them, 18 days? Sure, thank you.

Comment: Isn't there a max amount of drops per week or something? That would hinder it at greater play amounts.

Comment: @ShadowZ - the drop cap is 10 hours per week, so even assuming that every drop takes the maximum 70 mins, you'll only miss one or two. The other thing to keep in mind is that if a player plays less than the playtime cap in a week, their leftover time will be added to the next week, so a player who does not play for one week will receive twice as many items the following week.

Comment: If we are throwing in the swapping of weapons at scrap.tf into consideration, then it would only make sense to also consider the much rarer item drops that are not weapons, such as hats or paint. Most hats average a little over 1 refined in value, and depending on the hat you could be getting a lot more. To throw that into the calculations though would be very difficult, but just felt like I had to share :)

Comment: @WaveX - Hats and Paint drop so rarely I didn't think it was worth including. Personally, I don't think I've ever even seen a hat or paint as a random drop (and I have over 600 hours in the game). I've seen them drop as rewards for other things such as contracts, opening Mann Co Store packages or Xmas gifts etc. I've also left off crates which drop on their own timer separate to weapon drops